# Complex Analysis: Limits

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently working on the following problem:

Let c denote a complex constant. Then use the definition of limit to show that $$\lim_{z\to\ z_0} (z^2 + c) = z_0^2 +c$$

Definition of limit: For $$\lim_{z\to\ z_0} f(z) = w_0$$ $|f(z) - w_0| < \varepsilon$ whenever $0 < |z - z_0| < \delta$.

Here is my work so far:
$|f(z) - w_0| = |z^2 + c - z_0^2 - c| = |z^2 - z_0^2| = |(z + z_0)(z - z_0)| = |z + z_0||z - z_0| < \varepsilon$.

This is where I began to be confused. Initially, I thought I could just say that $\delta \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{|z + z_0|}$, but learned that this is not correct. It was then recommended to me that I try rewriting as such: $|z + z_0||z - z_0| = |z - z_0||z - z_0 + 2z_0|$. I don't really see the logic behind this. I am aware that this problem involves placing a restriction such that $\delta \leq 1$ and then finding the minimum of two values of $\delta$, but I don't see how nor why I would do such a thing.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: You need a bound on $\delta$ that does not depend on $z$. (Just on $z_0$ and $\varepsilon$.)

Comment: Technically, the order of thing is 1. fix $\epsilon$ 2. take $\delta$ 3. take any $z$ such that $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$, then 4. $|f(z)-w|<\epsilon$. So you should not use $z$ in the definition of $\delta$ ... which is why they suggested you such a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that
$$
|f(z) - w_0| = |z+z_0||z-z_0|
$$
You want this product to be $<\epsilon$.  Given $\epsilon > 0$, you may choose $\delta$ as small as you like and assume that $|z-z_0| < \delta$ to make it so.

Here is the scratch work: Suppose $\delta \leq 1$.  If $|z-z_0| < \delta$,
$$
|z + z_0| = |(z-z_0) + 2z_0| \leq |z - z_0| + 2 |z_0| \leq 1 + 2|z_0|
$$
Suppose also that $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|z_0|}$.  If $|z-z_0| < \delta$, then
$$
|f(z) - w_0| = |z+z_0||z-z_0| < (1 + 2|z_0|) \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|z_0|} = \epsilon
$$
which is what we wanted.  So we can choose $\delta = \min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|z_0|}\right)$ and both inequalities will be satisfied.

Here is the formal proof: Given $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|z_0|}\right)$.  Then since $\delta \leq 1$, if $|z-z_0| < \delta$, we have
$$
|z + z_0| = |(z-z_0) + 2z_0| \leq |z - z_0| + 2 |z_0| \leq 1 + 2|z_0|
$$
Moreover,
$$
|f(z) - w_0| = |z+z_0||z-z_0| < (1+2|z_0|) \cdot \delta \leq (1 + 2|z_0|) \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|z_0|} = \epsilon
$$
Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, we know $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = w_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what if we write $|z+z_0|=|z-z_0+2z_0|\leq |z-z_0|+2|z_0|<\delta+2|z_0|.$